# How to Change keras tensor values while model building

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras, artificial-intelligence

I am trying to make a model that has lambda layer that executes a custom function the output shape of it is to be of shape `(batch_size, 10, 5)

```
def yolo_head(x):
    boxes_ = x[:,:,:,:,1:5]
    confidence_ = x[:,:,:,:,:1]
    classes_ = x[:,:,:,:,5:]
    scores, boxes, classes = yolo_filter_boxes(boxes_, confidence_, classes_, threshold)
    scores, boxes, classes = yolo_non_max_suppression(scores, boxes, classes, max_box, threshold_iou)
    classes = tf.cast(classes, tf.float32, name=None)
    preds = scores*classes
    second_use = 0
    use = len(preds.get_shape().as_list())
    if use>1:
        second_use=preds.get_shape().as_list()[1]
    if use==1:
        preds = tf.zeros((preds.get_shape().as_list()[0],10,5), dtype=tf.dtypes.float32, name=None)
    elif second_use<10:
        current = tf.zeros((preds.get_shape().as_list()[0],10-second_use,5), dtype=tf.dtypes.float32, name=None)
        preds = tf.reshape(preds, (-1,1), name=None)
        preds = tf.concat(axis=1, values=[preds, boxes])
        preds = tf.concat(axis=0, values=[preds,current])
    else:
        preds = tf.reshape(preds, (-1,1), name=None)
        preds = tf.concat(axis=1,values=[preds, boxes])
    return preds

def create_model():
    total_ = 19*19*no_of_anchors*6
    pretrained_model = tf.keras.applications.MobileNetV2(
        input_shape=(512, 512, 3),
        include_top=False,
        weights='imagenet',
        pooling='max'
    )
    pretrained_model.trainable = False
    inputs = pretrained_model.input
    x=tf.keras.layers.Flatten()(pretrained_model.output)
    x = tf.keras.layers.Dense(total_, activation='relu',bias_initializer=tf.zeros_initializer(),kernel_initializer=tf.keras.initializers.Ones())(x)
    x = tf.keras.layers.Reshape((19, 19, no_of_anchors, 6))(x)
    outputs = tf.keras.layers.Lambda(yolo_head)(x)
    model = tf.keras.Model(inputs=inputs, outputs=outputs)

    model.compile(
        optimizer='adam',
        loss='categorical_crossentropy',
        metrics=['accuracy']
    )
    return model
```

[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/rJXNp.png [This is the output which shows error][1]